# Dynamically downsize an image

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

So I've got a large image 3000x2000 roughly and I want to span it across my website so it fills 100% width but stays the same proportions, but if I were to shrink the screen the image would resize automatically keeping the same proportions and no overflow scrolling.

```
<div class="row anfield">
    <img src="../Images/Anfield.jpg" />
</div>

.row{
width:100%;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

I have tried max-width / width 100% in the css anfield but neither worked.

```
<img style="max-width:100%" src="../Images/Anfield.jpg" />
```

This changes the width to 100% but doesn't resize the height accordingly.

Edit: I have tried adding this. Doesn't resize height at all

CSS

```
.fixed-ratio-resize { /* basic responsive img */
max-width: 20%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* IE8 */
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="anfield" src="../Images/Anfield.jpg" class="fixed-ratio-resize" />
```

Comment: try just `style="width:100%"`

Comment: look into srcset attribute for img if you want to distribute different sizes responsively. Good for avoiding loading in huge images for mobile devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need flexbox for this, just apply `width: 100%` to the image (nothing else), height is auto by default, which keeps it in proportion.

Comment: <div class="row anfield">
        <img style="width:20%" src="../Images/Anfield.jpg" />
    </div>     //This doesn't resize the height accordingly

Comment: did you remove the flex stuff from your `.row` class?

Comment: missed that part sorry, yeah i removed the class row and it work. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site.  It allows you to upload your image and generates not only smaller images but the code for you!
http://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/

Comment: Answer with external link is bad as when the link dies, it is of no use for future users. Add the important part into the answer itself.